# custom font with font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using Font-Face Generator [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)
to generate a custom font Europe bolditalic. Everything is working fine if I use only English letters, but my website is Russian and my custom font has no affect on Russian characters. Please help.

Comment: Are you using the "optimal" mode from that page? The default setting in "expert" is to enable "subsetting," to drop the non-Western glyphs from the font. You can disable subsetting or enable support for specific languages only in "expert."

Comment: I tried both disabling subsetting and selecting Ciryllic but did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

Either the font does not contain Cyrillic letters, or the font is not Unicode encoded. The latter is more probable. For example, a font called Europe and distributed (probably illegally) at http://www.broble.com/download-free-font/europe/ has some 8-bit encoding, so that it contains Cyrillic letters but not in proper places. You can see this is if you include letters like “ä” or “é” in your text – they appear as Cyrillic letters.

The solution is to find a better, properly encoded font.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

To your html header or, the font you are using don't support Russia.